# Looking for a sync program that can replace and restore files

Tags: windows, game, file-synchronization

I've been trying to find a Windows program that will sync files between two folders, and is able to replace files but also restore the original whenever I would want to. The folders would be on the same computer and would only sync one way.

Preferably I would be able to enable and disable different sets of files. On disabling, the program should remove these files from the target folder, and if any of those files overwrote existing files, these should be restored.

I want to use this as an easy mod manager for games (like GTA IV). The target folder contains many different files and subfolders.

I have attempted to write software for this purpose myself, but I realized that there may be a file sync program out there that can do this.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Will robocopy help?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [FreeFileSync](http://freefilesync.sourceforge.net/). It syncs folders, and can be configured to save backups of the original files. Other features include:

- Free
- Include/exclude files via filter
- Binary file comparison
- Keep versions of deleted/updated files
- Automate sync as a batch job
- Cross-platform and portable

Note that if you download the setup from SourceForge, make sure to uncheck then bundled adware before installing

Comment: It does appear to be a good program for file sync, but not exactly as I want it. Although it does allow storing updated files, I could not find an option to automatically restore these older versions.

Comment: @Spioner That can be done by creating another profile that performs a one way sync from the backup directory into your original one. But you're right, it's not really "automatic"

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155), is a powerful tools that I have used for years to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish.  It allows you to backup files to a remove location and them if need be restore them later.  You can set up a scheduled task to run this routinely.

Comment: "to a remove location" : did you mean "remote"? Could you fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it can automatically restore replaced files though. You can only restore them from the recycle bin.